# Invalidate all gcm tokens

Tags: android, google-cloud-messaging

My app uses gcm. Each time user logs in, new gcm token is registered and sent to my 3rd party server. Each time user logs out, gcm token is unregistered. This woks without any problems.

The problem is that when it comes to testing, tester can uninstall the app without loging out, and then install it back again and log into another account. Then he'll recieve two gcms from two different account. This means he'll recieve private gcms for account hes not currently loged into. This can even happen with live users sometimes.

GCM documentation states that gcm tokens can expire *sometimes* if the application is uninstalled. In practice, this never happens.
http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/gcm.html

GCM documentation also states that you can unregister GCM tokens by executing

```
Intent unregIntent = new Intent("com.google.android.c2dm.intent.UNREGISTER");
unregIntent.putExtra("app", PendingIntent.getBroadcast(this, 0, new Intent(), 0));
startService(unregIntent);
```

But this method doesn't seem to work if you try it after reinstall. I do recieve callback which tells me that token is unregistered, but gcm token still works ok.

My question is: can you ensure that there are no valid gcm tokens for your application? I'd really like to unregister all existing tokens during application first start, or at least reset them from the phone settings.

Comment: Hey Alexey, what solution you went for

Comment: I did what Mohamed Hafez suggested. I have a table with user ids and gcm tokens. Both fields are unique. When I recieve existing userId with new gcm token, I update gcm token. When I recieve existing gcm token with new user id, I update user id. That seems to cover all possible corner cases.

Comment: What happens if a user is logged in in two devices. I fear the two devices would not receive the gcm messages with this solution. Or am i missing something.

Comment: Yes, only the last device will recieve gcm messages. I believe that you can actually make only gcm token unique and allow userid duplicates, but that statement needs further testing. It depends on whether or not any device will always return same gcm token after reinstall (which appears to be true but it's not mentioned in documentation).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you'll receive an error when your server send a message to the invalidated registration id. I think you can catch this error to delete these registrations id from your database/datastore.

Also from the doc ([canonical id](http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/adv.html)):

> If later on you try to send a message using a different registration
>   ID, GCM will process the request as usual, but it will include the
>   canonical registration ID in the registration_id field of the
>   response. Make sure to replace the registration ID stored in your
>   server with this canonical ID, as eventually the ID you're using will
>   stop working.

Comment: I am new to GCM, so I'm not sure of rthis

Comment: Thank you, I'll try this. But there is still one problem - I'll have to send this gcm message in order to understand that old token was replaced. That means that user will still recieve private messages from previous loged in user, at least for once. I can probably add userId to every gcm packet and check it on client side, but I still hope there is a better way to accomplish what I need.

Answer (score 2):

GCM tokens for your app are unique for each device, so if you ever get a different user telling you they are using the same GCM token as some other user, then you know that the situation you described has occurred. Basically, every time you receive a GCM token, you should delete all older records that have that same GCM token before assigning it ONLY to the new user.